# Laravel take from collection with offset

Tags: php, laravel

I got this collection

```php
$collection = collect([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I know I can use the method take() to bring the X first elements of the collection

```php
$collection = collect([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$chunk = $collection->take(3);

$chunk->all();

// [0, 1, 2]
```

But I was wondering, if is there a way to add an offset to the take() method or do something that produce a result like this

```php
$collection = collect([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$chunk = $collection->take(3,2);

$chunk->all();

// [2, 3, 4]
```

any clue?

Comment: Why do you spend your time writing a lengthy (and nice!) question instead of looking at the docs? Everything is there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use skip method

```
$collection = collect([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$chunk = $collection->skip(2)->take(3);
$chunk->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `splice` method removes and returns a slice of items starting at the specified index:

You may pass a second argument to limit the size of the resulting collection:

```
$collection = collect([0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$chunk = $collection->splice(2, 3);

dd($chunk->all());
```

you can also use `slice` method if you want retain all the the values in the collection for future use

For more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-splice

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice()` method instead of `take()`